# Can't proceed a simple search

Tags: search

Hi after a migration on Drupal 7.69 / CiviCRM 5.33.2 everything went fine except that now we can't perform a simple search https://domain.net/civicrm/contact/search?reset=1 when there should be contacts.

If there is no contact (i.e searching inside a specific tag that is empty), it quickly returns the right information saying 'no results'. But if there are some contact (in type, group or tag), it keeps searching and after a while comes to an internal error (500).

The quick search top-left works fine but the advanced search also fails.

We guess that CiviCRM tries to write the search query in the civicrm_cache table in the database but fails, maybe this hypothesis is not relevant.

How could we improve this point? Any advice?

Comment: If it's error 500 then check the web server log (e.g. apache/nginx) - it will say the error.

Comment: this one is on a shared server so unfortunately I can't access server log :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  After updating to [5.34.0](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/5.34.0.md#synopsis), this issue was fixed for me.